# how to run browser independence in java script without using ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, activexobject

i was using ActiveXObject in my code is for IE. Now i would like run my application in browser independence. I found in google that ActiveX is not a requirement for browser independence and also that many functions already works in IE if i eliminate the activeX coding and uses the chrome and firefox coding. But i have no idea to how to remove. can any one help me.

Here is my code snippet

```
if (typeof (xmlDoc.transformNode) != "undefined") { // IE6, IE7, IE8
        return xmlDoc.transformNode(xsltDoc);
    }
    else {
        try { // IE9 and greater
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate");
                var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");
                xslDoc.loadXML(xsltDoc.xml);
                xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc;
                var xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
                xslProc.input = xmlDoc;
                xslProc.transform();
                return xslProc.output;
            }
```

Regards

Comment: Gecko engine has a native `XSLTProcessor`. Have a look at it: `window.XSLTProcessor`

Comment: Hi dsuckau, thanks for your quick reply. can you please give me any one reference link.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XSLTProcessor